# where vs at where

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm not sure if a preposition is needed.

A new roundabout will be added **where/at where** the south road meets the main road currently in a T-intersection.

Comment: "at where" is wrong.

Comment: We may say "at what place," "at which place," or "at that place,", but not, "at where." Just another idiosyncrasy of the English language.

Comment: *A new roundabout will be added [at the place] where the south road meets the main road currently in a T-intersection.* Also the position of "currently" seems off to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: The preposition is technically correct, but it sounds strange to many English speakers, so omitting it is probably best.

First of all, let's deal with "where" alone. In that case, the subordinate clause functions adverbially; it modifies the verb phrase "will be added" and (of course) answers the question "where". That is certainly correct.

Next, let's establish that "where" can begin a nominal clause (sometimes called a "noun clause", "substantive clause", etc.). According to [one website](https://www.english-for-students.com/substantive-clauses-1.html):

> Noun clauses may be introduced (1) by the subordinate conjunctions that, whether (whether ... or), and if (in the sense of whether); (2) by the interrogative pronouns who, which, what (3) by the interrogative adverbs where, whence, whither, how, why, when.

For example, such a clause can function as a subject:

> Where you live doesn't matter.

Such a clause can also function as an object of a preposition. For example:

> Every day he commutes from where he lives to where he works.

If such a clause can function as the object of "from" and "to", then surely it can also function as the object of "at":

> A new roundabout will be added at where the south road meets the main road currently in a T-intersection.

However, this is likely to sound unusual to most English speakers, so if you insist on using "at", then something like this would probably be better (though lengthier):

> A new roundabout will be added at the place at which the south road meets the main road currently in a T-intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The word *where* can replace *at what place*, so the combination *at where* is redundant.

In your example, though, this would be grammatical:

*A new roundabout will be added at the place where the south road currently meets the main road in a t-intersection.*

In that example, the word *at* is part of the preposition phrase *at the place*.  Then, the word *where* is a relative pronoun introducing a clause.

You could remove the word *where* entirely by saying
*... at the place at which the south road ...*
but it works better using *where* for the relative clause.

Note that the comment about the position of *currently* is right, and it's moved in the rephrasing above.